# 404 error showing alternate resource and still giving console message

Tags: php, .htaccess, server, http-status-code-404

This is just a curious question. I was hot-linking an image from youtube (just for testing purposes) and after a few days I found that the image is not found.

I looked at the chrome console and saw that I got an error which is fine:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (OK)

But the odd thing is that it is still rendering a resource (image) in that url:

https://yt3.ggpht.com/-Lb_brNR-U94/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/sHqrEtEBc4I/s88-c-k-no/photo.jpg

I have implemented such feature in my website using htaccess Rewrite like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .*$ /image-not-found.png [L]
```

But I dont get a console message saying resource is not found as I am rewriting the url of the image not found.

How do I implement the feature like what Google implemented?

I am using PHP at server side.

Comment: Try with final `[L,R=404]`

Comment: thanx. it works. Please add it as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ /image-not-found.png [L,R=404]
```

that performs rewriting with code 404